# How to associate .log files with LTFViewer on Windows 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, log-files, windows-explorer, file-associations

[Large Text File Viewer](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=693) is fast for opening megabyte and gigabyte large log files.

However on Windows Server 2008 (SBS) the File Explorer fails to open .log files with this application. LTF viewer can't even be chosen as default application to open this `.log` file extension. LTFViewr5u.exe is not listed as "recommended application".

[image]

#### Regression

One can point "Open with" file properties dialog window of any .log file to the executable (`LTFViewr5u.exe`), .log files are still not opened. Instead Windows insists on opening log files with the slow Notepad app.

How to permanently associate and open all .log files with LTFviewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Recommend LTFViewr5u.exe

One or both of these registry entries will associate .log files with LTFview5u.exe:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.log\OpenWithProgids]
"LTFviewer"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\LTFviewer\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\LTFViewr\\LTFViewr5u.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Note: adjust `C:\\Program Files\\LTFViewr\\` to your location, like:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.log\OpenWithProgids]
"LTFviewer"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\LTFviewer\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LTFViewr\\LTFViewr5u.exe\" \"%1\""
```

#### 2. Logoff & logon

LTFViewr5u.exe should now list as recommended application to open .log files with.

[image: Windows: Openen met dialoog: Kladblok]

#### 3. Change default "Open with"

Select LTFViewr5u.exe and apply that selection.